# Any way of changing NetBeans application font?

Tags: fonts, java, netbeans

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ugly fonts in Netbeans - How can i make it use the system font?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32624/ugly-fonts-in-netbeans-how-can-i-make-it-use-the-system-font)

I'm running Ubuntu and Netbeans 7.0.1 and default fonts look like ...

[image: Screenshot of what fonts look like with Netbeans 7.0.1]

Why, oh why it looks so hideous compared to Windows, for example.

Is there any way of changing fonts that application is using by default?