# Ugly fonts in NetBeans

Tags: java, fonts, netbeans

Is there a way to fix the ugly fonts in NetBeans that REALLY WORKS on Ubuntu 13.04 and NetBeans 7.3.1? I tried everything I could find on this topic but nothing worked for me.

Please don't tell me to do any of these, as I've tried them all:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/65194/31521 (fonts are bigger but still ugly)
- https://askubuntu.com/a/60920/31521 (doesn't change anything, same with `_JAVA_OPTIONS`)
- https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=215785#c7 (fixed in NetBeans 7.2.1)
- Switch to Oracle JVM (absolutely no changes)

Also I'm not interested in just changing the editor font as that doesn't really solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix ugly fonts in Eclipse/Netbeans/Jetbrains:

```
sudo apt-get remove fonts-unfonts-core
```

Best,
M

Answer (score 0):

To use the system fonts into the netbeans you need to append a code into the `netbeans_default_options` present in the `netbeans.conf` file.

The code is below:

```
-J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way I found is using the Nimbus lnf through the build in Options

```
Options > Miscellaneous > Windows > Preferred look and feel: [ Nimbus ] (needs restart)
```

Don't try to change the lnf with the --lnf Nimbus command line switch. Also do **not** use the Dynamic Look and Feel Changer Plugin, which will destroy the Coloring of Nimbus in netBeans