# How to fix Netbeans 7.4 (and Netbeans 8.0) Ugly Text and Popups in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, fonts, netbeans, platform-integration

I've tried various workarounds, but I haven't yet found a way to make the fonts in Netbeans look right. I've tried changing the config files of Netbeans, and trying the instructions [*here*](http://ileriseviye.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/how-to-solve-the-ugly-font-problem-of-java-applications-in-ubuntu-12-10/) that don't seem to have any effect since they aren't installed in 13.10.

My specific question has three parts: **1)** why is every font 18 or less drawing characters with lines that are only one pixel thick, and the . and : are making only one pixel on the screen - unless I force bold, or a huge font of 19 or more:

(If this is a Java problem, why is Eclipse fine?)

Bad font, thin and not easily readable
[image: Bad font, thin and not easily readable]

Almost okay font - but HUGE:
[image: Almost okay font - but HUGE]

If you look at the terminal or native Ubuntu apps they don't show up as only one pixel - is there a solution for this?

**2)** Why does Netbeans show a box at the end of the line, when text is too long and overflows to the next displayed line?

**3)** Maybe not related, but why do popup-windows of Netbeans have this small dropdown below them? This happens both with the netbeans-starting info window, and the git changes popouts from the bar with the line-numbers.

[image: Ugly Netbeans dropdown]

Ugly git integration showing changes:

[image: Netbeans Git dropdown]

**Update**

No change in 8.0, unfortunately :(

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of (2)?

Answer (score 2):

## 1. Fonts

I searched a bit on this issue, but I didn't find a way on how to make the fonts "bolder". The issue does not seem to be Ubuntu 13.10-specific however. The link you refer to is about another bug, that actually makes some text a bit thicker. (see below)

I did find some things that can help you, I do not know if you will find them better, feel free to try them.

### Make it use system fonts in menu and other places

This [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/937200) actually makes a lot of the text nicer in my opinion. Just `sudo apt-get install fonts-unfonts-core` and restart netbeans. (only works with JDK7) It will look like this:

[image: Buggy font]

However, this does not change the editor font.

### Change theme

Changing the theme changes the fonts a bit, however, it does not make them thicker.

```
gedit ~/netbeans-7.4/etc/netbeans.conf
```

And add `--laf Metal` to the `netbeans_default_options`

The default theme is "GTK". I like "Metal" myself. you can find a complete list of themes on [the netbeans website](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NBLookAndFeels)

[image: Metal Theme]

### Other options

i have not tried it out myself but [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/36339/172367) seems promising. Let me know if it looks better...

## 2. Overflow

I do not understand what you mean. Maybe a screenshot would help?

## 3. Weird windows that have wrong size, wrong shading

Seems to be a bug in java. If i use JDK6 it is actually way worse...

Comment: Can I have JDK7 and still use the Android SDK? I attached another screenshot, see updated question.

Comment: I do not think it would be a problem. If it is a problem, you can always just remove JDK7.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using gtk+ theme, there is a solution that is already implemented by default on ubuntu 15.04 which fixes the menu on java swing applications.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danjaredg/jayatana
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jayatana
```

Answer (score 0):

For the ugly fonts part, there is a solution.
add the following code into the end of the default properties section in the `netbeans.conf` file.

```
-J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to `Tools` > `Options`. Select the appearance tab and choose the preferred look and feel to Metal. See if it fixes the theme and fonts.

If you like to have a darker theme, go to `Tools` > `Plugins` and install "Darcula LAF for NetBeans".