# Netbeans IDE Looks

Tags: 14.04, themes, netbeans, platform-integration

My Netbeans IDE 8.0 doesn't gets looks like GTK and dosen't use preferences (UI) of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
It's default apps can looks like most Ubuntu UI Colors. Why it dosen't looks like that?[image: Netbeans IDE on Ubuntu 10.04]

It using black bacground color from entire OS

Why it dosen't looks like that, see background color of menu item 
My Ubuntu 14.04 Looks like that
[image: Netbeans IDE on Ubuntu 14.04]
It should use black color as menuItems bacground.

please tell me how i can apply Look of entire OS Ubuntu 14.04 to  Netbeans IDE 8.0 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Do any of the answers at [Netbeans menu is awful in Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199622/netbeans-menu-is-awful-in-ubuntu-completely-unreadable-and-bleh-to-look-at-an) help? You can also switch themes in netbeans, see answer to [How to fix Netbeans 7.4 (and Netbeans 8.0) Ugly Text and Popups](http://askubuntu.com/questions/390057/how-to-fix-netbeans-7-4-and-netbeans-8-0-ugly-text-and-popups-in-ubuntu-13-10)

Comment: I don't  face problem with font ,UI  background color of MenuItem

Comment: The second part of the answer to "How to fix Netbeans..." covers changing the theme. Have you tried that?

Comment: Conf file doesn't update it's access denied

Comment: You will have to adapt it for 8.0, probably `gedit ~/netbeans-8.0/etc/netbeans.conf`